# Spring boot nested native sql query is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```java
@Query(value = "select m from IN_MESSAGE m where m.masterOrderNo=(select n.masterOrderNo from IN_MESSAGE n where n.orderNo=:orderNo)", nativeQuery = true)
public List<InMessageDO> findAllByOrderNo(@Param("orderNo") String orderNo);
```

Above code is in my Jpa Repository.

```java
List<InMessageDO> inMessages = inMessageRepo.findAllByOrderNo(input.getOrderNo());
```

Above line shows how I am calling JPA method in my Application. Whenever above line is getting executed I am getting exception.

> 'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException' exception.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not using a native query at all. `SELECT m FROM ...` is not native SQL.

You have to use `SELECT *` or `SELECT m.*` like this (not tested at all but `select m` should be the problem):

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM in_messagedo m WHERE m.MASTER_ORDER_NO = (SELECT n.MASTER_ORDER_NO FROM in_messagedo n WHERE n.ORDER_NO = :orderNo)", nativeQuery = true)
public List<InMessageDO> findAllByOrderNo(@Param("orderNo") String orderNo);
```

Edit: Also, if your `@Entity` is named `InMessageDO` check how is your table name, because you are trying to read `IN_MESSAGE` table, and should be `in_messagedo` or something similar.

Also your query has to be the same as your DB, not as your object attribute name, so you have to look for `MASTER_ORDER_NO` instead of `masterOrderNo`. And I suposse `orderNo` has the same problem.

Also, the last `orderNo` is not neccesary to edit, this is the parameter variable.

Comment: Hi J.F. Thank you for reply. I have tried SELECT * and SELECT m.* But I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: I've tested with my DB and works ok. Update with more details from the stack trace error. Also check your table is named `IN_MESSAGE` and not `IN_MESSAGEDO` or something similar.

Comment: From stack trace: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "M"."MASTERORDERNO": invalid identifier

Comment: And I also checked the table name. It is IN_MESSAGE

Comment: Check how is named the row `masterorderno` in the DB

Comment: Column name in database is MASTER_ORDER_NO

Comment: You query has to be the column name, not variable name.

Comment: You are welcome! Also if the issue has been resolved, mark answer as accepted is apreciated :)

Comment: Hey how your entity looks? Which columns it should have